# Which web server is installed with the nextcloud open on Ubuntu live server?

Tags: system-installation, webserver

Which web server is installed when you choose the nextcloud option?

[image]

Comment: Which version of Linux are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [the source repository](https://github.com/nextcloud-snap/nextcloud-snap), the Nextcloud server packaged consists of:

- Nextcloud 22
- Apache 2.4
- PHP 8.0
- MySQL 8
- Redis 6
- mDNS for network discovery

Comment: Thanks - knowing it was a Snap package was the piece of information I didn't know either.